# How to remove localizations from a video using YouTube API v3?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need help. I am not able to remove localizations with YouTube API v3.

The docs say: If you are submitting an update request, and your request does not specify a value for a property that already has a value, the property's existing value will be deleted.

My default language is "en". I have uploaded "fr" and "de" localizations. I am only able to remove one localizations, but not both. How do I need to construct the JSON data?

1. Removing localizations in JSON doesn't work.
2. Empty titles and descriptions don't work.
3. Removing only one key "fr" or "de" in JSON works, but I want to remove all localizations.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem.

When the default language of your video is "en", you want to set "en" in localizations to reset all other languages in the localizations property.